# Why Are My Quotes Disappearing? (GNU make/sh)

Tags: shell, makefile, cygwin, gnu-make

I'm working with GNU makefiles on Windows at my work and trying to learn as I go. The recipe line that's giving me so much trouble is

```
$(SED) -n "/Format ID $(def_format_id)/,/End Format ID $(def_format_id)/ p" "$(def_format_altsec_header)" > "$(def_format_file)"
```

which fails for `C:/GNU1_06/bin/sed: -e expression #1, char 7: unterminated address regex`.

To try to understand the behavior that I've been banging my head against for the last couple hours, I changed it to a simple command to cause sed to launch and stall so I can look at exactly what's getting invoked with Process Explorer:

```
$(SED) -e s/blah//
```

ProcExp shows that make is directly invoking sed with the expected command line. If you single-quote the argument, however, make invokes EXACTLY the same thing (no quotes to be found on the command line).

Things get really strange when you use double-quotes.
Make invokes `C:/GNU1_06/bin/sh.exe -c "C:/GNU1_06/bin/sed -e \"s/blah//\""`
So far so good, but then sh invokes `C:\GNU1_06\bin\sed.exe -e s/blah//`
as if the escaped quotes were never there.

What exactly is going on here? Why are my quotes disappearing into the nether before sed ever gets to run?

UPDATE: This appears to be related to the fact that $(SED) is a fully-specified path. This behavior is not observed when sed.exe is used alone (and ProcExp proves that that uses the same copy of sed as the fully-specified path).

This problem reproduces in the minimal makefile

```
.PHONY: all
all:
    C:/gnu1_06/bin/sed.exe -n "/Format ID 01010101/,/End Format ID 01010101/ p" "./FORMAT/BIGHILO/AC/99/sff_altsec_01_data.h"
```

Comment: Can you include the output you get when you run make? Also if you're using Cygwin then Process Explorer may not be showing you the arguments that the Cygwin utilities are actually using.

Comment: The exact error from sed for the original failure (first code) is: C:/GNU1_06/bin/sed: -e expression #1, char 7: unterminated address regex

Comment: Can you add the make output as well, where it shows the command it executes?

Comment: Because it immediately fails I can't look at it in ProcExp. When I do -n it prints C:/GNU1_06/bin/sed -n "/Format ID 01010101/,/End Format ID 01010101/ p" "./FORMAT/BIGHILO/AC/99/sff_altsec_01_data.h" > "./build/BIGHILO/AC/99/Process/Format/default_format_data.c". However, the simpler test cases make it highly unlikely that that's what ACTUALLY gets executed.

Comment: Make normally prints each command before it executes it, so it should've printed the sed command on the line before the error message that sed printed out. If it not doing that then either you've left out the `@` at the beginning of your command or there's something very odd going on. Maybe you should post a minimal complete verifiable example makefile that demonstrates the problem. Include the complete output of the example. Also verify that you're actually using the Cygwin versions of make, sed and sh.  The `GNU1_06` pathname is odd for a Cygwin installation.

Comment: It's worth noting that if I substitute $(SED) -n for $(ECHO) I get this written to the file: /Format ID 01010101/,/End Format ID 01010101/ p ./FORMAT/BIGHILO/AC/99/sff_altsec_01_data.h

Comment: I had to play around for quite a while to get the problem to reproduce in a fresh makefile. What seems to provoke it is the command (sed) being a fully qualified path. This behavior is not observed when just using sed or sed.exe (and yes, I verified with ProcExp that it is C:/GNU1_06/bin/sed.exe in both cases)

Comment: I'm confused. The line that gives you trouble has `$(SED) -n` but your examples then use `$(SED) -e`. Which is it?

Comment: Why don't you write a script that performs the `sed` command and invoke that? Here you are trying to pass arguments containing spaces through two layers of variable and quote interpretation, one by `make` and one by the shell  (`cmd` or `sh`?), which is confusing.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. I get no errors with Cygwin make and sed when using a fully qualified path, including the Windows drive letter.  with Something must be wrong with your Cygwin installation. As I said before check to be sure that you're using Cygwin versions of `make`, `sh` and `sed`, and that they all come from the same version and installation of Cygwin.

Answer (score 1):

When *make* decides to rebuild a target it expands the recipe, and then passes each line in the result separately to a new invocation of the the shell.

*Except* that, as an optimisation, there is no need to pass it to the shell when the line contains no meta characters (i.e., characters that would be specially interpreted by the shell, things like `<`, `>`, `"`, `&` etc.). In this case *make* just executes the line directly. AFAICT this list is not documented.

Personally, when on windows, I use cygwin make exclusively. Why? Because it is much more compatible in all these sorts of corner cases. I once got to a place with mingw make where 5 backslashes were not enough, and 6 were too many. Ugh!

Note also that command-line parsing in windows is insane. When does the `echo` built into `cmd.exe` remove double quotes? Trust me, cygwin 'just works'™ (parallel building is worth price of entry alone).

Comment: Yeah, Cygwin isn't just working. That said, our distribution is horribly outdated, and we developers have frequently butted heads with IT and "if it ain't broke don't mess with it!" over it (especially Perl).

Comment: Sympathies. I'm currently stuck on svn 1.6 (and I can secretly use 1.6.17). I really miss the last 3½ years' worth of svn development. And there's me thinking the whole point of IT is to keep tools up to date.